# Does default analyzer overlap custom analyzer in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, analyzer

I want use custom analyzer for some fields, and use default analyzer for others, so I wrote like this:

```
{
   "settings": {
       "analysis":{                                                                                                                                             
           "analyzer": {                                                    
               "default": {                                             
                   "type": "keyword"                                    
                },                                                     
                "my_lowercase":{                                       
                   "type": "custom",                                      
                   "tokenizer": "whitespace",                             
                   "filter":[ "lowercase"]                                
               }                                                        
            }           
        }                                                               
    },                                                                   
    "mappings":{                                                         
        "test_string":{                                                      
            "_all":{                                                     
                "enabled":false                                            
            },                                                           
            "properties":{                                               
                "title":{                                                  
                    "type":"string",                                         
                    "analyzer":"my_lowercase"                                
                },                                                         
                "content":{                                                
                    "type":"string",                                         
                    "analyzer":"my_lowercase"                                
                }                                                          
            }                                                              
        }                                                                
    }
}
```

The length of field "content" is longer than 32766. When I wrote like above， it returned the error like this:
[Document contains at least one immense term](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ls44J.png).
If I delete the default analyzer, it works well.
So it seems that custom analyzer is overlapped by the default analyzer, and the tow fields use the default analyzer.  Does anybody know the reason? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Your settings are not correct, you're missing the `analysis` section

```
"settings": { 
  "analysis": {                 <--- add this                                                                                                                                            
   "analyzer": {                                                    
       "default": {                                             
           "type": "keyword"                                    
        },                                                     
        "my_lowercase":{                                       
           "type": "custom",                                      
           "tokenizer": "whitespace",                             
           "filter":[ "lowercase"]                                
       }                                                        
   }      
  }                                                         
},
```

Comment: I did add "analysis" in my code. I just forgot writing it  when I asked this question. Sorry.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. I think the "mapping" section is how I index the data.

Comment: Data is indexed like this:{
  "title": "test",
  "content": "hello world hello world hello world ",
}.  Is this what you want to know?

Comment: Please show the full command you're using... using curl, Sense, or whatever

Comment: My apology for forgetting telling you. I simplified the data structure when I asked the question. And I checked the actual script again and found that there was something wrong with the script.  I will delete the question. Thank you very much.